# how do I wait for data to be fetched in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

so i am fetching data from mongodb atlas and then store it in an array, then i pass it in pug , but issue here is what i think is that pug file is rendered before data could be fetched .
here is the code

```
if (req.body.day === "Monday") {
            var slotData = []
            monday.find({})
                .then(found => {
                    // console.log(found);
                    var inislotData = found[0][req.body.slots]
                    const namesToDeleteSet = new Set(inislotData);
                    slotData = namearray.filter((name) => {
                        // return those elements not in the namesToDeleteSet
                        return !namesToDeleteSet.has(name);
                    });
                    for (let index = 0; index < slotData.length; index++) {
                        const element = slotData[index];
                        member.find({name:element})
                            .then(foundnumer=>{
                                // console.log(foundnumer[0].number)
                                numberarray.push(foundnumer[0].number)
                                // console.log(numberarray)
                            })
                    }
                    
                })
                .then(dat=>{
                    finaldata = [slotData,numberarray]
                    console.log(finaldata[1])
                    res.render('data', { finaldata })   
                })
        }
```